# php ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm writing a php script to insert data into an Oracle database, and I'm getting ORA-01861: literal does not match format string  when I try to run it. It has something to do with the date and they way it's calculated, but I'm not sure how/where to fix it. In the table, the log_date is type date. Below is the section of code that I'm working with for the date after I've already established the db connection. Does it need to go in my $query definition?

```
$ticks = $mnemonic->timestamp . "\n";
$seconds = ($ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
$day = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $seconds);

$query = "INSERT into TLM_Item(log_date) Values('$day')";

$updt = ociparse($conn, $query);
    if(!$updt){
    print "No query \n";
    exit;
    }

    $r = ociexecute($updt , OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracles default date format is not YYYY-MM-DD.  Fortunately, though, Oracle supports the keyword `DATE` so support dates.  I haven't used it in this context, but it should work:

```
$query = "INSERT into TLM_Item(log_date) Values (DATE '$day')";
```

Alternatively, you could use the built-in function `to_date()`:

```
$query = "INSERT into TLM_Item(log_date) SELECT to_date('$day', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL";
```

Comment: The first option didn't work, but the second one did.
Comments: 
1) Typo: in the second option, "HH:MI:DD" should say "HH:MI:SS"
2) If you type it like as above you will get an error "ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12". If you instead type "HH24:MI:SS" it will work.

Comment: Now, just a follow up question: if I want to insert other values in addition to the date, do I just use the whole expression "SELECT to_date('$day', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:DD') FROM DUAL" in a Values() expression along with the other values to be inserted?

Comment: Also, when I go to the DB to check the entries, the dates show up as: 10-JAN-14 with no time included. What is causing it to not appear?

Comment: @fcr91 . . . The default format for printing out dates in Oracle is to leave out hte time (use `to_char()` if you want more details).  If you want to insert more columns, use `insert . . . select`.  It does everything `insert . . . values()` does and more.